# GAS apps script execute web app with token - 403 forbidden

Tags: google-apps-script, google-cloud-platform

I have 2 scripts deployed as web app.
First has function doGet which creating post request to second app with function doPost. 
I'm getting Forbidden when calling first doGet function

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>Forbidden</TITLE>
</HEAD>
<BODY BGCOLOR="#FFFFFF" TEXT="#000000">
<H1>Forbidden</H1>
<H2>Error 403</H2>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

First app: 
-doGet function 
-Execute the app as: User accessing the web app 
-Who has access to the app: Anyone
-manifest
  "oauthScopes": ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.external_request", "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly"],

```
function doGet(e) {

  var url = #url_to_second_app

  var headers = {
    "Authorization" : "Bearer " + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()
  };

  var params = {
    "method":"post",
    "headers": headers,
    "muteHttpExceptions": true
  };

  var response;
  try{
    response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url,params);
  }catch(err){
    response = err;
  }  
  Logger.log(response);
  return ContentService.createTextOutput(response);
}
```

Second app: 
-doPost function 
-Execute the app as: Me 
-Who has access to the app: Anyone

```
function doPost(e) {
return ContentService.createTextOutput("hello world!");
```

Comment: My understanding is that the doPost and doGet are connected to the end point of the url that you get with `ScriptApp.getService().getUrl()`  so if you have two forms on a webapp and one has method="GET" then it will use the doGet() and if the other has method="POST" then it will use the doPost().  If you don't have a doPost() you can just use the doGet for both.  But it wasn't intended for you to call the doPost() or doGet() methods from inside your script

Comment: What error message are you getting when turning   ```muteHttpExceptions``` to ```false```?

Answer (score 0):

> Who has access to the app: Anyone

To access the  second app anonymously, the second script should be published as

> Anyone **even anonymous**

Alternatively, the second app's drive should be shared with first app's script[<sup>1</sup>](https://github.com/tanaikech/taking-advantage-of-Web-Apps-with-google-apps-script/blob/master/README.md#error-messages).

Comment: Both scripts are on same drive

Comment: @Szymon Then you need to send Bearer token in the Authorization headers to identify that it's you that's making the fetch call. Sample [here](https://github.com/tanaikech/taking-advantage-of-Web-Apps-with-google-apps-script/blob/master/README.md#share-project-of-web-apps-with-client-users)

Comment: as you can see Bearer token is attached to request (request from doGet)

Comment: @Szymon 1. Are both scripts  running as  the same Google account? 2. Could you try increasing the scope of `drive.readOnly` to `drive` and redeploy a new version? 3. If that doesn't work, downgrade both apps to rhino engine from v8 and redeploy both apps?

Comment: Still this same error. When i changed access to the second app from 'anyone' to 'anyone even anonymous' and sent a request with authorization token i ve got 403, but without this header request passed